# MVC Controller and Com Object VB .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sqlbase

I have a development where i made a Com dll to communicate with Centura SQLBase:

`COM DLL Code`

```
adaptor.SelectCommand() = New SQLBaseCommand("SELECT COMPANY_ID,COMPANY_NAME FROM COMPANY", myConnection)
    Dim ds = New DataSet()
    adaptor.Fill(ds, "COMPANY")

    Dim myArray As New ArrayList 
    For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        myArray.Add(row)
    Next 

    MsgBox(myArray(1).Item(0)) //This shows 102
    MsgBox(myArray(1).Item(1)) //This shows Maui Mu-Mus
Return myArray
```

So `myArray` is storing the right values; however in my MVC Controller i got an arrayList with 23 rows(which is fine) but all of them empty.

Here is my `Controller Code GET: /Gupta/GetCiudades`

```
 Function GetCiudades() As JsonResult

        Dim objConn As Object 
        objConn = Server.CreateObject("TestGupta.ComClass1")

        Dim ciudadJson As ArrayList = objConn.getCompanies()

        Return Json(ciudadJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) 

 End Function
```

`Ajax Code`:

```
 $.getJSON("Gupta/GetCiudades", null, function (ciudades) {
        ciudades = (JSON.stringify(ciudades));
        console.log(ciudades);
 });
```

`console.log Result:`

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

The question is: if in the com object is showing the right values, then why in the controller the rows are empty??

Comment: So myArray is storing the right values; however in my MVC Controller i got an arrayList with 23 rows(which is fine) but all of them empty....why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed:**

**Com+ Code:**

```
 Public Function getCompanies() 
    Dim myConnection As SQLBaseConnection = New SQLBaseConnection()
    myConnection.ConnectionString = getConn ' Obtenemos la cadena de conexion desde el get
    'Abrimos la conexion con Gupta
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim adaptor = New SQLBaseDataAdapter
    adaptor.SelectCommand() = New SQLBaseCommand("SELECT COMPANY_ID,COMPANY_NAME FROM COMPANY", myConnection)
    Dim ds = New DataSet()
    adaptor.Fill(ds, "COMPANY")
    myConnection.Close()
    Return ds
End Function
```

**Controller Call**

```
Dim ds = objConn.getCompanies()

        Dim arrayInformaticos As New ArrayList
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            arrayInformaticos.Add(New Informatico(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0), ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)))
        Next
        Return Json(arrayInformaticos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Solution based on ArrayList of Objects in the controller, and now the Com method returns a Dataset.